# Boost multi_index container with composite key, custom comparer and partial index search

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a class like this (simplified example):

```
class A {
  public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
    const std::string& getID() const;
    const std::string& getLabel() const;
    bool getFlag() const;
    float getValue() const;
  private:
  ...
};
```

I need a container that is indexed by a unique combination of `(id, label)` and also a unique combination of `(label, flag, value)`. I also need it to be sorted by the second index by label first followed by flag followed by decreasing values if flag is true and increasing values if flag is false. So after creating key extractors I'm doing something like this:

```
typedef boost::multi_index::composite_key<
  Ptr, extractor_id, extractor_label
> id_label_key;
typedef boost::multi_index::composite_key<
  Ptr, extractor_label, extractor_flag, extractor_value
> label_flag_value_key;
...
typedef boost::multi_index_container<Ptr,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
      boost::multi_index::tag<by_id_label
      id_label_key
    >,
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
      boost::multi_index::tag<by_label_flag_value>,
      label_flag_value_key,
      Compare
    >,
  >
> Items;
typedef Items::index<by_label_flag_value>::type Items_by_label_flag_value;
```

where Compare is defined as:

```
struct Compare {
  bool operator() (const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<label_flag_value_key>& k, const boost::tuple<float,bool>& q) const {
    return compare(k.value->getLabel(), k.value->getFlag(), k.value->getValue(),
      q.get<0>(), q.get<1>(), q.get<2>()
  }
  bool operator() (const boost::tuple<float,bool>& q, const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<label_flag_value_key>& k) const {
    return compare(q.get<0>(), q.get<1>(), q.get<2>(), 
      k.value->getLabel(), k.value->getFlag(), k.value->getValue(),
  }
  bool operator() (const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<label_flag_value_key>& k1, const boost::multi_index::composite_key_result<label_flag_value_key>& k2) const {
    return compare(k1.value->getLabel(), k1.value->getFlag(), k1.value->getValue(),
      k2.value->getLabel(), k2.value->getFlag(), k2.value->getValue())
  }
  bool compare(const std::string& l1, bool f1, float v1, const std::string& l2, bool f2, float v2) const {
    if (l1 != l2) return l1 < l2;
    if (f1 != f2) return f1;
    return f1 ? (v1 > v2) : (v1 < v2);
  }
};
```

Now, I can perform queries like this:

```
Items_by_label_flag_value::const_iterator it = items_by_label_flag_value.find(boost::make_tuple("A", true, 0.1));
```

However, if I try to perform a partial query - say, retrieve all items that have the same label - my code won't compile:

```
std::pair<Items_by_label_flag_value::const_iterator, Items_by_label_flag_value::const_iterator> range = items_by_label_flag_value.equal_range(boost::make_tuple("A"));
```

I know why it does not compile: in the comparer I explicitly use `.get<0>()`, `.get<1>()` and `.get<2>()` but partial search tuple does not have `<1>` and `<2>` elements. What I do not know is how to create the correct comparer. If I try to add two more functions to it that takes tuples of one element only then the compiler complains of ambiguity in `operator()` call.

I also understand that `composite_key_result` is supposed to be an opaque object and I should not be using its insides.

So my question is how to create the required index and the correct comparer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your original solution, you need not use composite keys for your second index as your `Compare` extractor is basically trying to replace the machinery automatically generated by `composite_key`/`composite_key_compare`. The following has been (lightly) tested to work:

```
struct LBFCompare
{
  bool operator() (const A& x, const A& y) const {
    return compare(
      x.getLabel(), x.getFlag(), x.getValue(),
      y.getLabel(), y.getFlag(), y.getValue());
  }
  bool operator() (const std::string& x, const A& y) const{
    return compare(x,y.getLabel());
  }
  bool operator() (const A& x, const std::string& y) const{
    return compare(x.getLabel(),y);
  }
  template<typename T0>
  bool operator() (const boost::tuple<T0>& x, const A& y) const{
    return compare(x.get<0>(),y.getLabel());
  }
  template<typename T0>
  bool operator() (const A& x, const boost::tuple<T0>& y) const{
    return compare(x.getLabel(),y.get<0>());
  }
  template<typename T0,typename T1>
  bool operator() (const boost::tuple<T0,T1>& x, const A& y) const{
    return compare(x.get<0>(),x.get<1>(),y.getLabel(),y.getFlag());
  }
  template<typename T0,typename T1>
  bool operator() (const A& x, const boost::tuple<T0,T1>& y) const{
    return compare(x.getLabel(),x.getFlag(),y.get<0>(),y.get<1>());
  }
  template<typename T0,typename T1,typename T2>
  bool operator() (const boost::tuple<T0,T1,T2>& x, const A& y) const{
    return compare(x.get<0>(),x.get<1>(),x.get<2>(),y.getLabel(),y.getFlag(),y.getValue());
  }
  template<typename T0,typename T1,typename T2>
  bool operator() (const A& x, const boost::tuple<T0,T1,T2>& y) const{
    return compare(x.getLabel(),x.getFlag(),x.getValue(),y.get<0>(),y.get<1>(),y.get<2>());
  }
  bool compare(const std::string& l1, const std::string& l2) const {
    return l1 < l2;
  }
  bool compare(const std::string& l1, bool f1, const std::string& l2, bool f2) const {
    if (l1 != l2) return l1 < l2;
    return f1 < f2;
  }
  bool compare(const std::string& l1, bool f1, float v1, const std::string& l2, bool f2, float v2) const {
    if (l1 != l2) return l1 < l2;
    if (f1 != f2) return f1;
    return f1 ? (v1 > v2) : (v1 < v2);
  }
};

struct by_id_label{};
struct by_label_flag_value{};

typedef boost::multi_index_container<
  Ptr,
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
      boost::multi_index::tag<by_id_label>,
      id_label_key
    >,
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
      boost::multi_index::tag<by_label_flag_value>,
      boost::multi_index::identity<A>,
      LBFCompare
    >
  >
> Items;
typedef Items::index<by_label_flag_value>::type Items_by_label_flag_value;

int main()
{
  Items c;
  c.insert(Ptr(new A("id","label",true,1.0)));
  Items_by_label_flag_value& i=c.get<by_label_flag_value>();
  i.find("id");
  i.find(boost::make_tuple("id"));
  i.find(boost::make_tuple("id",true));
  i.find(boost::make_tuple("id",true,1.0));
}
```

The ambiguity problems you mention are due to the fact that you're probably looking up by passing tuples with `const char*`s rather than fully-formed `std::string`s: in this situation there are implicit conversions and seemingly 1-, 2- and 3-sized tuples are equally good candidates (an implementation problem with tuples IMHO.) The solution is to templatize those `LBFCompare::operator()`s that take tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting problem! The simplest way to solve it I can think of is: add the following to your class

```
class A {
  ...
  float getTaggedValue()const{return getFlag()?-getValue():getValue();}
  ...
};
```

and then equip your second index with a regular composite key on `(label,tag,tagged_value)` When doing searches with tuples `(l,t,v)` you mustn't forget to have `v`negated if the tag is true (with a little more effort, you can have `getTaggedValue` return a special type, say a `pair<bool, double>`, so that you don't inadvertently pass directly an unchecked float into the tuple.)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I that's exactly what I did too (which also made the custom comparer unnecessary) and I think it is a correct solution. Another similar method is to have two variables to store value and populate one with the value and the other one with zero depending on the flag; this method will be preferable when the value type isn't float but something that is relatively expensive to copy (e.g. some sort of Decimal) so that we can always return const ref in key extractor. I'm still interested, however, how the original problem may be solved - or why it can't.